# Finding 'wh' sentence in a given paragraph using regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

**What is your name? How do you do? I am in way. Where are you? Are you hungry? I like you.**

In the above paragraph, the answer should pick all the wh questions like 
"What is your name?
Where are you?"

How to achieve above using regular expression in java?

Comment: What part do you have trouble with? Building the regex or using a regex library in Java? Since you've tagged with `nsregularexpression` - do you need to use this library, or it suffices to use the standard JFC regexen?

Comment: i just want to find question mark (?) at first then among them i want to extract Wh questions using regula expression

Comment: Why not use a regex for the entire question, _then_ care about the position of the question mark? If you want to use regexes (not that they're needed here), do it completely.

Comment: Suggest providing examples of anything you've attempted.

Comment: @Jan, If the `java` tag is correct, I assume `nsregularexpression` isn't.  Newcomers tend to use that tag because it's the only one they can find that contains the full words "regular expression".  I'm removing it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I tested this code, so it should work now. It looks for all the `Wh` words I could think of in the English language, instead of trying to find `Wh` itself in a word.

```
String text = "What is your name? How do you do? I am in way. Where are you? Are you hungry? I like you. What about questions that contain a comma, like this one? Do you like my name, Whitney Houston? What is going to happen now, is you are going to do what I say. Is that clear? What's all this then?";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:Who|What|When|Where|Why|Which|Whom|Whose)(?:'s)?\\s+[^\\?\\.\\!]+\\?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

List<String> questions = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) questions.add(m.group());

for (String question : questions) System.out.println(question);
```

I just realized there could be a question starting with `Who's`, so now it allows `'s` after the `Wh` word.

Comment: What about questions that contain a comma, like this one?

Comment: `Do you like my name, Whitney`? matches `Whitney?`. It shouldn't.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it to prevent those issues.

Comment: The question is tagged Java, what's the point of posting an answer in Python? A regex in Python isn't guaranteed to work in Java.

Comment: This still matches within `Do you like my name, Whitney Houston?`

Comment: Does it avoid all the problems now?

Comment: `Whoever made this, did he really think of all the possibilities?` :-) I _am_ impressed, however :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple version (for OP example sentence) ...

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Wh[^\\?]*\\?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

For more advanced matching (ensures Wh word is at beginning of sentence) ...

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|\\?|\\.) *Wh[^\\?]*\\?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
            String match = m.group().substring(m.group().indexOf("Wh"));
            System.out.println(match);
    }
```